# Read Extended Boot Record in windows c++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, filesystems

I am trying to read the extended boot record. The location of the extended boot record is i suppose at the first sector from absolute start offset.
First i read the MBR (Master Boot Record) to get the partition info i get the extended partition start offset,partition number and total length of partition.

I want to know how to figure out which partition is the first logical drive for that extended partition and in case of the partition being extended partition is there any metadeta stored after the MBR as well??

Is there a way i can get this information  ??

Thanks
Is there a way

Comment: Does this help, or do you need more? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/488296/Partition-Tables-Explained

Comment: Thanks but it just explains partition table info.

Comment: Isn't the "Extended Boot Record" whatever is read by the code in the MBR? I'd almost suggest emulating the BIOS environment.

Comment: Do you mean NTFS boot record? If so try to read [this](http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/mbr/NTFSBR.htm)